# How can I re-enable the web interface of a dd-wrt router with no SSH or telnet connection?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, administrator

I accidentally disabled my D-link router's web interface. I installed dd-wrt firmware on it. The router's SSH and telnet connections are disabled. I don't want to reset the router.

How can I enable the web interface?

Comment: [Head](http://superuser.com/users/106123/head): What if there's also no access via https? Only hard reset?

Answer (score 11):

I recommend following these steps in the future: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=29181

```
nvram set httpd_enable=1
nvram set http_enable=1
nvram commit
```

You can just reboot or start httpd from the command line:

```
httpd -p 80
```

I followed them and got mine to work.

Answer (score 5):

SSH and then:

```
nvram set remote_management=1
nvram set http_wanport=8080 
nvram set httpsd_enable=1 
nvram set https_enable=1
nvram set remote_mgt_https=1 
nvram commit 
reboot
```

Then connect:

https://wanIP:8080/

Comment: He mentioned that SSH is disabled.

Comment: SSH is not enabled..

Comment: This is still very helpful if you have ssh enabled, though.

Comment: It was very helpful for me, as I did have SSH but locked myself out of the HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Ok..I got it..
I access it over https..and entered username and password.

Keep in mind,there are protocols (http and https) that router used to display its web-based interface.

thank you guys..

Comment: Feel free to mark this as accepted. You won't get rep, but it does let the system know it has an accepted answer, and future goolgers will be able to find it faster.

Comment: I had the same issue, but had to DISABLE TLS before the browser let me connect via HTTPS. I do believe modern browsers will see older firmare HTTPS as insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You can soft-reset the router - i.e., keep the "reset" button pressed for 30 seconds. This will bring back most of the router's settings to its defualt.